# Weird characters appearing in mysql general log

Tags: mysql

I'm noticing weird values in my mysql general log... entries like this:

```
select rsip, rspool_id from IPv4RS where (rsip between '¬à' and '¬à')

select id, vip from IPv4VS where (vip between '�J�B' and '�J�B')
```

The application itself that connects to this database is running fine... and showing correct results.  I'm just wondering how I can track this type of an issue down....

I'm trying to open up the log in different text editors to see if it appears differently / for some clues as to whats going on...

If you have any suggestions on where I should start to track this issue down, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you saving the log/looking at it with an appropriate character encoding?

Comment: That's what I'm playing around with right now in different text editors.